# Why does a push_back on an std::list change a reverse iterator initialized with rbegin?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

According to some STL documentation I found, inserting or deleting elements in an std::list does not invalidate iterators.  This means that it is allowed to loop over a list (from `begin()` to `end()`), and then add elements using push_front.

E.g., in the following code, I initialize a list with elements a, b and c, then loop over it and perform a push_front of the elements.  The result should be cbaabc, which is exactly what I get:

```
std::list<std::string> testList;
testList.push_back("a");
testList.push_back("b");
testList.push_back("c");

for (std::list<std::string>::iterator itList = testList.begin(); itList != testList.end(); ++itList)
   testList.push_front(*itList);

for (std::list<std::string>::const_iterator itList = testList.begin(); itList != testList.end(); ++itList)
   std::cout << *itList << std::endl;
```

When I use reverse iterators (loop from `rbegin()` to `rend()`) and use push_back, I would expect similar behavior, i.e. a result of abccba.  However, I get a different result:

```
std::list<std::string> testList;
testList.push_back("a");
testList.push_back("b");
testList.push_back("c");

for (std::list<std::string>::reverse_iterator itList = testList.rbegin(); itList != testList.rend(); ++itList)
   testList.push_back(*itList);

for (std::list<std::string>::const_iterator itList = testList.begin(); itList != testList.end(); ++itList)
   std::cout << *itList << std::endl;
```

The result is not `abccba`, but `abcccba`.  That's right there is one additional c added.

It looks like the first push_back also changes the value of the iterator that was initialized with rbegin().  After the push_back it does not point anymore to the 3rd element in the list (which was previously the last one), but to the 4th element (which is now the last one).

I tested this with both Visual Studio 2010 and with GCC and both return the same result.

Is this an error?  Or some strange behavior of reverse iterators that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard says that iterators and references remain valid during an insert. It doesn't say anything about reverse iterators.  :-)

The `reverse_iterator` returned by `rbegin()` internally holds the value of `end()`. After a `push_back()` this value will obviously not be the same as it was before. I don't think the standard says what it should be. Obvious alternatives include the previous last element of the list, or that it stays at the end if that is a fixed value (like a sentinel node).

---

Technical details: The value returned by `rend()` cannot point before `begin()`, because that is not valid. So it was decided that `rend()` should contain the value of `begin()` and all other reverse iterators be shifted one position further. The `operator*` compensates for this and accesses the correct element anyway.

First paragraph of 24.5.1 Reverse iterators says:

> Class template `reverse_iterator` is an iterator adaptor that iterates from the end of the sequence defined
>   by its underlying iterator to the beginning of that sequence. The fundamental relation between a reverse
>   iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity:
>    `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any reference for the technical details?

Comment: Added a quote from the standard.

Comment: @BoPersson: Note that the "remain valid" only concerns iterators pointing to existing elements. The behavior for singular values (like `end()`) is thus not specified.

Comment: @MatthieuM - It doesn't say so explicitly, at least no in the `list` section. It says "Does not affect the validity of iterators and references" in [list.modifiers]. I would have preferred "iterators to existing elements" here...

Comment: @BoPersson: in 23.1/11 it says *Unless otherwise specified [...] invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container.* The distinction is clearly made there.

Comment: "The value returned by rend() cannot point before begin(), because that is not valid" - end() returns a value after rbegin() and nobody has a problem with that

Comment: @immibis `end()` and `rbegin()` could both point to the past-the-end element

Comment: @M.M If the list is empty, then sure, otherwise rbegin() returns a reverse iterator pointing to the last element.

Comment: @immibis not according to what I'm reading on this thread (especially Jerry Coffin's answer). Distinguish between what the implementation of the reverse iterator points to , and the result of dereferencing the iterator (which moves along by one from where the iterator pointed)

Comment: @M.M The implementation details shouldn't matter. That's why they're implementation details. The specification says that I have an iterator pointing to the last element, and it says that iterators aren't invalidated except by erasing the element they point to (IIRC), hence adding a new element should not invalidate this iterator and it should continue pointing to the element it was previously pointing to.

Comment: @immibis understanding the implementation details helps to explain why reverse_iterators are invalidated by insertion

Answer (score 7):

I think to understand this, it's best to start by re-casting the `for` loop as a `while` loop:

```
typedef std::list<std::string> container;

container testList;
testList.push_back("a");
testList.push_back("b");
testList.push_back("c");

container::reverse_iterator itList = testList.rbegin(); 
while (itList != testList.rend()) {
    testList.push_back(*itList);
     ++itList;
}
```

Along with that, we have to understand how a `reverse_iterator` works in general. Specifically a `reverse_iterator` really points to the element *after* the one you get when you dereference it. `end()` yields an iterator to just *after* the end of the container -- but for things like arrays, there's no defined way to point to just before the beginning of a container. What C++ does instead is have the iterator start from just after the end, and progress to the beginning, but when you dereference it, you get the element just *before* where it actually points.

That means your code actually works like this:

[image]

After that, you get pretty much what you expect, pushing back B and then A, so you end up with ABCCCBA.

Comment: Can you point to the specification, or even a reference site, where it indicates that reverse_iterators work this way? (If not, that doesn't make the explanation wrong necessarily, but if it's not wrong it's an implementation bug)

Comment: @immibis: §[reverse.iterators]/1: "The fundamental relation between a reverse iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity: &*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)."

Answer (score 0):

Try using an iterator for both. Try:

```
std::list<std::string>::iterator i = testList.end();
```

and reverse through with --i

Comment: I am not looking for an alternative solution.  I want to know why the reverse iterator suddenly points to something else, because this seems to be in contradiction with the documentation (see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html).