# C++ list iterator reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, stdlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does a push_back on an std::list change a reverse iterator initialized with rbegin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085570/why-does-a-push-back-on-an-stdlist-change-a-reverse-iterator-initialized-with)

I got a piece of code as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main(){
    std::list<int> l;
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    std::list<int>::iterator it = l.begin();
    std::cout << *it << std::endl; // 1
    l.push_front(0);
    std::cout << *it << std::endl; // 1
    std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit = l.rbegin();
    std::cout << *rit << std::endl; // 2
    l.push_back(3);
    std::cout << *rit << std::endl; // 3
}
```

output:

```
1
1
2
3
```

It looks like that after I define the forward iterator `it`, if I call `push_front()`, the position of `it` WILL NOT change. However, after I define the reverse_iterator `rit`, if I call `push_back()`, the position of `rit` WILL change.

Should this be considered as an inconsistency? It really doesn't make any sense to me that one of them moves while the other stays the same.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I can't find the specific detail in the spec right now, but it must be due to the fact that 'rbegin()' returns 'end()' through the 'reverse_iterator' adaptor.  The 'reverse_iterator' variable would sit on 'end()' while 'push_back' prepended the value.

Comment: certainly sounds reasonable. +1

Comment: @mmodahl Not end(). If it was end() he couldn't dereference it. Anyways: Don't assume anything about iterators if you modify the collection in question after creating them.

Answer (score -1):

`std::list` does not invalidate iterators. As you see with the regular iterator, iterators on `std::list` point to the same element even after the list is modified.

Reverse iterators, on the other hand are implemented as `std::reverse_iterator<iterator>`, which according to [C++ STL documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/), maintain an iterator pointing to the element *before* the one that is returned by the iterator, which in this case is the end of the list.

Comment: Why the downvote? What did I get wrong? This is exactly what was said in the other answer.