# std::list and std::for_each: where is my end?

Tags: c++, foreach, iterator, stdlist

Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<std::function<void()>> list;
    list.push_back([&list](){ list.push_back([](){ throw; }); });
    std::for_each(list.cbegin(), list.cend(), [](auto &&f) { f(); });
}
```

It compiles and throws an exception at run-time.
My guess was that only the first lambda is executed by the `std::for_each`, but apparently I was wrong: if I append another lambda at the end of the list, the iteration reaches also that lambda.

Let's revert the example (`push_front` instead of `push_back` and `crbegin`/`crend` instead of `cbegin`/`cend`):

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<std::function<void()>> list;
    list.push_front([&list](){ list.push_front([](){ throw; }); });
    std::for_each(list.crbegin(), list.crend(), [](auto &&f) { f(); });
}
```

Because of the previous example, I expected this to compile and crash as well.
Instead it compiles and doesn't crash. This time, the function pushed to the front of the list is not executed.

The question is quite simple: is this correct?
Why are so counterintuitive the two examples?

In the first case I was expecting something different and I was wrong, that's not a problem.
Anyway, I would have expected coherence between the two loops. I mean, the second function is executed in one case and it is not executed in the other case, but I'm iterating from a *begin* to an *end* in both cases.
What's wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Compiler used ?

Comment: @GillBates Both GCC 6.1 and clang 3.9 works as described in the question. Is it relevant? I didn't think it could be an issue of the compiler.

Comment: Shouldn't it add indeed the lambda (first example)? The iterators are not invalidated like in the case of `std::vector`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a push\_back on an std::list change a reverse iterator initialized with rbegin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085570/why-does-a-push-back-on-an-stdlist-change-a-reverse-iterator-initialized-with)

Comment: @vsoftco _They are not invalidated_ doesn't mean that _they can change_. Instead in the first case the _end_ changes position, in the second case the _end_ is fixed.

Comment: Linked answer shows `push_back` but same should apply for `push_front`.

Comment: @skypjack I think I see what you mean now, thanks for clarifying. Of course you won't write code like this in production :)

Comment: @skypjack no. You're at prev(end()). Then you push_back, and push back inserted a new node between your current iterator and the end

Comment: @GillBates I'm not sure it's a duplicate actually.

Comment: It comes very close at least, and should provide a lot of information why it happens.

Comment: Wait, what? `throw;`  doesn't throw an exception; it goes straight to `terminate` because there's nothing to rethrow.

Comment: @T.C. That was the purpose. A minimal example is... Well, a minimal example.

Comment: "throws an exception at run-time"

Comment: @T.C. And you are right, absolutely. When one is right, is right. Not the best wording actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, the results you get seem to be what I expected. Let's walk through you first example:

1.

```
list.push_back([&list](){ list.push_back([](){ throw; }); });
```

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[lambda]----[end]
```

2​. start iterating over the list

Iteration 1:

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[lambda]----[end]
^
+-- current
```

`f()` calls `list.push_back([](){ throw; });`

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[lambda]----[inner_lambda]----[end]
^
+-- current
```

Iteration 2:  (`++current`)

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[lambda]----[inner_lambda]----[end]
            ^
            +-- current
```

`f()` calls `throw;`

end

---

---

Now let's do the other direction.

First of all, look at how reverse iterators are actually represented - this is important (image from cppreference): [image: reverse iterators]

The important part is: reverse end points to normal begin. But the problem is, with a list, one *can* insert something before `begin`, but it's not possible after `end`. That invariant is broken with reverse iterators.

1.

```
list.push_front([&list](){ list.push_front([](){ throw; }); });
```

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
|
|+-- list.rend().base()
||
||          +-- list.rbegin().base()
vv          v
[lambda]----[end]
```

2​. start iterating over the list

Iteration 1:

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
|
|+-- list.rend().base()
||
||          +-- list.rbegin().base()
vv          v
[lambda]----[end]
    ^           ^
    |           +---- current
    |
    +--------- passed list.rend()
```

`*current` yields `[lambda]`.

`f()` calls `list.push_front([](){ throw; });`

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
|
|+-- list.rend().base()
||
||                            +-- list.rbegin().base()
vv                            v
[inner_lambda]----[lambda]----[end]
                      ^           ^
                      |           +---- current
                      |
                      +--------- passed list.rend().base()
```

Note that the passed `list.rend().base()` has not changed - but it doesn't point to the first (past the last reversed) element anymore.

Iteration 2:  (`++current`)

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
|
|+-- list.rend().base()
||
||                            +-- list.rbegin().base()
vv                            v
[inner_lambda]----[lambda]----[end]
                      ^  ^
                      |  +---- current
                      |
                      +--------- passed list.rend().base()
```

`current` == `passed list.rend().base()`

the end

---

---

Now let's try the other one **by my mistake this part is relevant for forward iterating over the list**:

1.

```
list.push_front([&list](){ list.push_front([](){ throw; }); });
```

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[lambda]----[end]
```

2​. start iterating over the list

Iteration 1:

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[lambda]----[end]
^
+-- current
```

`f()` calls `list.push_front([](){ throw; });`

Iterator to current is not invalidated and/or made to point somewhere else than it already was pointing.

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[inner_lambda]----[lambda]----[end]
                  ^
                  +-- current
```

Iteration 2: (`++current`)

List state:

```
+-- list.begin() (not necessarily what has been passed to for_each)
v
[inner_lambda]----[lambda]----[end]
                              ^
                              +-- current
```

end

Comment: It doesn't consider the fact that the actual _begin_ and the actual _end_ iterators are copied, thus fixed within `std::for_each`. In the example you are only considering _begin_ and _current_. My doubt is about the fact that _end_ (let me say) _changes_.

Comment: @skypjack *end* doesn't change, and current is the begin you passed. But your lambda operates on the whole list, not the subset you passed. Therefore in the second example it adds an element before your current begin.

Comment: I see you point. It is a bit counterintuitive for me, but it doesn't mean that it is _wrong_ actually. Let me think twice about it.

Comment: @skypjack I think you're thinking in terms of indexes, which is, pardon the term, vector thinking ;) If you're on the first element of the list, and you push at the front, then indeed then first+1th element of the list - the next iteration - would be the current actual element.  And that's what'd happen if you used index + insert(begin()) with a vector (or even an iterator with enough memory reserve()d).  But list is moral anathema to an index, the elements never move and are never invalidated (sans actual deletion). If you changed the list before, it doesn't change the list after the element.

Comment: Or, maybe to try from another side: there's a reason why push_front/push_back/insert have constant complexity with list. It's because they only ever operate on 1 element + links to its neighbours.

Comment: _vector thinking_ :-D ... Thank you for the detailed explanation, really appreciated. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack well, this is embarrassing. I only now noticed that you're using reverse iterators in the second example. I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: @skypjack I'm not sure how clear those ascii arts are. The core problem hasn't changed, though. You're iterating between past-the-end and last-known-begin (direction irrelevant), and are inserting elements outside of that range (before last-known-begin), thus you'll never reach them.

Comment: They look good. Anyway, I'll look into the matter in the evening, so please be patient. Right now I cannot do that for I'm not at home. Sorry.