# In std::list, does the iterator point to a specific node or a position on the list?

Tags: c++, list

So if I'm writing

```
list<int> temp;
temp.push_front(3);
list<int>::iterator it=temp.begin();
temp.push_front(5);
temp.erase(it);
```

In this scenario, am I deleting 3 or 5? Does the iterator maintain it's reference to Node 3, or does it contain a reference to temp.begin(), causing it to delete 5?

Comment: Have you tried running the code, and printing out the contents of the list afterwards? Honestly, even when you understand how things work, the results often surprise some people. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086296/179910

Comment: To the node, of course (looking at the documentation again, it seems obvious because it can only be implemented that way, but the documentation only say that "it will not be invalidated"... where exactly is it specified what will it point to afterwards?)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. 
I did run the code and I realized that it points to the node.
That comment about reverse iterators was super interesting. Didn't know that's how it worked :)